# Spring security - exceptionIfMaximumExceeded=false not killing oldest session

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have the following conifuration in spring security:

```
 <bean  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
                <constructor-arg ref="clusteredSessionRegistryImpl" />
                <property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
                <property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="false" />
            </bean>
```

Now, as per the docs - this configuration should allow users to login again and again while each logins will invalidate the oldest session (if exists.) this doesn't work, I can login many times from the same username. and each time a new session will be created but no invalidation takes place.

p.s if i change exceptionIfMaximumExceeded to "True" it works as intended. (i get an error when logging in the 2nd time)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom `UserDetails` implementation then you have to properly defined the `equals()` and `hashcode()` method in that class

Follow this link 
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/99166-maximum-sessions-1-does-not-work